# How to sample from a Wishart distribution?

Tags: matlab, wishart-distribution

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution), we know that $n$, the degrees of freedom, should be larger than $p-1$ where $p$ is the dimension of the scale matrix.

Also, from the bottom part of the same article, we see "Bartlett decomposition" to sample Wishart distribution where the diagonal element is generated from $\chi^{2}(n - i + 1)$.

However, if you type the following commands in Matlab 2011b:

```
Sigma = eye(2)
nu = 1
wishrnd(Sigma,nu)
```

It will return something! Here, `nu` (degrees of freedom) is no longer greater than the dimension of the scale matrix, right?

Also, if you look close in to the implementation of `wishrnd` by issuing `type wishrnd`, we see the following line:

```
a = diag(sqrt(chi2rnd(df-(0:n-1))));
```

Clearly, the implementation generates $\chi^{2}(n-i)$ instead of $\chi^{2}(n-i+1)$.

Something incompatible here?

Comment: See the first answer. This is a special case. But, I do doubt that the parameterization for this function differs from the normal definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any incompatibility here; in fact, I think the Wikipedia article you cite provides your answer:

> In fact the above definition can be extended to any real $n > p − 1$. If $n \leq p − 2$, then the Wishart no longer has a density—instead it represents a singular distribution.

Having $n<p$ doesn't mean the distribution is undefined; clearly from the definition of the Wishart distribution we can generate a sample by taking the (scaled) sample covariance matrix of $n$ i.i.d. multivariate Gaussian random variables. The result will be singular in the case of $n<p$, but that doesn't mean the distribution is undefined or that sampling from it should cause an error.

EDIT: The above assumes you're talking about integer values of $n$; otherwise you do get an error as expected:

```
>> wishrnd(eye(3), 1.5)     
Error using wishrnd (line 50)
Degrees of freedom must be a positive integer, or a non-integer value larger than
the dimension of SIGMA minus 1.
```

Comment: Thanks for the insights about the case. However, this still does not related to how it is generated, right?

Comment: First: notice that the code you're referring to is only used for large df (df>81+p). In the test case you give, it's just generating random normals using the code in the preceding block. Second: the code matches the Wikipedia page; `df-(0:n-1))` is the same as `df-1+(1:n))`. If the line read `df-(1:n)` then that would correspond to $\chi^2(n-i)$ like you claim.