# Generate complex random vectors distributed as $\textit{proper}$ Complex Gaussian

Tags: matlab, random-generation

This is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877279/generating-a-random-complex-vector-in-matlab)  and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24288/how-to-sample-from-a-wishart-distribution) question.

How can we generate (in Matlab) complex random vectors which are distributed according to the *proper* complex distribution $\mathcal{CN}(\vec\mu, \Sigma)$, where $\vec\mu$ is mean and $\Sigma$ is complex hermitian positive definite matrix (lets assume that pseudo-covariance is zero)?

Please note that I am not talking about wishrnd(Sigma,df) which generates ensembles of real random matrices. I am interested in complex numbers which have a fixed mean and covariance and which may be correlated.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Lets say we try to generate complex random vectors from a $\textit{proper}$ complex Gaussian distribution, which is defined as $f(z)=\frac{1}{\pi^N |\Lambda|} e^{-(z-b)^H\Lambda^{-1}(z-b)}$ with $z \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times 1}.$ [This paper](http://speedy.sh/RBxkH/Proper-Complex-Gaussian.pdf) says that (at page. 1295, equation-8) that for such a distribution the covariance matrix of real parts must be equal to covariance of imaginary parts of $z$, i-e $\Lambda_{cc}=\Lambda_{ss}$ and their cross covariance must be anti-symmetric i-e  $\Lambda_{cs}=\Lambda_{cs}^T$.

So, according to the paper the real covariance matrix,$\Phi$, (of order $2n \times 2n$)  should have this structure:

$$
\Phi=\begin{bmatrix}
    \Lambda_{cc} & -\Lambda_{cs}^T \\
\Lambda_{cs} & \Lambda_{ss} 
\end{bmatrix} $$

This is only possible when $\Lambda_{cs}=0=\Lambda_{cs}^T $ and rank of $\Phi$ is made equal to $2n$.

But I think I am wrong some where in interpretation, could someone help me out.

Comment: Are you looking for help programming Matlab or do you need guidance on the random number generation process? Since a complex vector of length $n$ is identical to a real vector of length $2n$, there shouldn't be any difficulty obtaining what you need by means of the usual multivariate Normal random number generators.

Comment: Just need an idea on how to do it. 
So, is it always $\textit{True}$ that complex Gaussian vector of length $n$ can be fully specified (at least statistically) by length $2n$ real Gaussian vector?

Comment: Yes.  The complex Normal distributions are just another way to parameterize real Normal distributions.  One way to see that is to count dimensions.  In the [Wikipedia notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_normal_distribution), there is a Hermitian covariance matrix $\Gamma$ which has $n(n-1)/2$ complex and $n$ real parameters; and a symmetric "relation matrix" $C$ with $n(n+1)/2$ complex parameters. That's equivalent to $2n(n-1)/2+n+2n(n+1)/2=(2n)(2n+1)/2$ real parameters, which is exactly the number needed for a $2n\times 2n$ real covariance matrix.

Comment: @whuber would you please have a look at my attempt above.